# How to get the 360° image from Google Street View

Tags: python, google-street-view, 360-panorama, google-street-view-static-api

I am working on a project where I have developed a Python code that retrieves the 360° image of a specific point (lat, lon) using the Google Street View API. I used this request to obtain 4 images of the same point but with different headings, and it works well.

```
!google_streetview --location=45.457872348690394,-73.44886627392344 --heading='0;90;180;270' --fov=90 --save_downloads=/content/
from PIL import Image
import glob
import numpy as np
files= glob.glob('/content/gsv_*.jpg')
list_images= []
files.sort(key=lambda f: int(''.join(filter(str.isdigit, f)))) # rangement dans le bon ordre
for f in files:
  print(f)
  image = Image.open(f)
  #image.show()
  list_images.append(np.array(image))

temp= np.hstack(list_images)
Image.fromarray(temp).show()
```

**Is the Google Street View API billed per request or per image (in my case, I sent a single request but obtained 4 images) ?
** Is there any other method through which I can directly obtain the 360° images?

Comment: [Google StreetView Usage and Billing](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/usage-and-billing)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! As per your post, there seems to be nothing wrong with your code right? But your question is about billing? If so, please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and contact GMP support if you have further questions with regards to billing with Google Maps API. https://developers.google.com/maps/support#contact-maps-support